# Prestashop add new regisration field error

Tags: php, html, prestashop

I use Prestashop 1.4 and want to add new field in the file *authentication.tpl* i add corrcet html input field, in the file /classes/Customer.php, the field is not required and i don't have added it into *$fieldsRequired* in the variable *$fieldsSize* i added it with size of 132 characters and in the *$fieldsValidate* string validation.

This is ok. but the field is not inserted in the database (field already inserted in #_customer table).

In the function **getFields()** i added this field, and if i add this field i get error message, field code is:

```
$fields['amazonresellerid'] = pSQL($this->amazonresellerid);
```

And there is problem, if i add this then i ger error message on submit : "An error occurred while creating your account.", all field name are exactly written, can't understand, what i do here wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of adding a field on prestashop 1.4 with an overload:

Add field to database :

```
ALTER TABLE `ps_customer` ADD `amazonresellerid` VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL AFTER `date_upd`
```

Create Customer.php in /override/classes/ and put this code:

```
<?php

class Customer extends CustomerCore
{
    public $amazonresellerid;

    protected   $fieldsValidate = array(
        'secure_key' => 'isMd5',
        'lastname' => 'isName',
        'firstname' => 'isName',
        'email' => 'isEmail',
        'passwd' => 'isPasswd',
        'id_gender' => 'isUnsignedId',
        'birthday' => 'isBirthDate',
        'newsletter' => 'isBool',
        'optin' => 'isBool',
        'active' => 'isBool',
        'note' => 'isCleanHtml',
        'is_guest' => 'isBool',
        'amazonresellerid' => 'isString'
    );

    public function getFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getFields();
        $fields['amazonresellerid'] = pSQL($this->amazonresellerid);
        return $fields;
    }

}

?>
```

And add input in authentication.tpl :

```
<p class="text">
    <label for="amazonresellerid">{l s='Amazon reseller id'}</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="amazonresellerid" id="amazonresellerid" value="{if isset($smarty.post.amazonresellerid)}{$smarty.post.amazonresellerid}{/if}" />
</p>
```